# Why does merging empty partition boundaries generate lots of data in the transaction log?

Tags: sql-server-2014, database-partitioning, transaction-log

I have the following partitions:

```
ObjectId  | PartNo | Boundary            | Rows
----------+--------+---------------------+-----
146099561 |     97 | 2013-10-04 23:59:59 |   0
146099561 |     98 | 2013-10-05 23:59:59 |   0
146099561 |     99 | 2013-10-06 23:59:59 |   0
146099561 |    100 | 2013-10-07 23:59:59 |   0
146099561 |    101 | 2013-10-08 23:59:59 |   0
146099561 |    102 | 2013-10-09 23:59:59 |   0
146099561 |    103 | 2013-10-10 23:59:59 |   0
....
```

All of them are empty. 
They were previously switched out to a temporary table which was truncated and subsequently deleted. All this happened very fast and created minimal log entries in the transaction log.

Weirdly, merging the empty boundaries of the partition function creates a non-trivial amount of data in the transaction log. Note that the partitions around each boundary are completely empty. This means we aren't moving lots of bytes around. The database is using "Full Recovery Model".

This is what I use to merge a boundary. I am doing it in a loop (not shown here) of course.

```sql
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION TransactionTemporaryPartitionFunction ()
    MERGE RANGE('2013-10-09 23:59:59')
```

Why does it create so much data in the transaction log?